# Change wordpress templates to Arabic

Tags: wordpress, templates, themes, arabic, right-to-left

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wordpress and RTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973216/wordpress-and-rtl)

i have a wordpress template suitable for the english language, i want to make it suitable for the eastern languages such as arabic & hebrew, this means to flip the site design from Left to Right & vice versa. enabling me to write at the eastern language i want...any one have an answer i will be helpful to have.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to check this out:
http://ar.wordpress.org

Or even give a shot at installing an Arabic version of Wordpress found here: 
http://www.ar-wp.com

You can edit the CSS to change the text-direction to ltr for Eastern languages and vice-versa for Western. You can make this conditional.

There's also this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-rtl/